# Fabric custom object

Tags: fabricjs

```js
fabric.ThreePointArc = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Circle, {
        type: 'threePointArc',

        points: [], //array of startPoint, intermediatePoint, endPoint

        arcCenter: new fabric.Point(null, null),

        arcBounds: null,

        radius: null,

        initialize: function (points, options) {

            if (!points || points.length === 0) {
                return;
            }

            this.points = points;

            this.callSuper('initialize', options);

            // supports only originX and originY as center
            this.originX = this.originY = 'center';
        },

        _set: function(key, value) {

            this.callSuper('_set', key, value);

            if (key === 'points') {
                this._calcArcCenter();
                this._calcDimensions();
                this.setCoords();
            }
            return this;
        },

        setRadius: function(value) {
            this.radius = value;
            return this;
        },

        _calcDimensions: function() {

            this._calcArcAngles();
            this.setRadius(cMath.getLength(this.arcCenter, this.points[0]));
            this._calcArcBounds();

            this.width = this.arcBounds.width;
            this.height = this.arcBounds.height;
            
            this.top = this.arcBounds.y + this.arcBounds.height / 2;
            this.left = this.arcBounds.x + this.arcBounds.width / 2;
        },

        _calcArcCenter: function() {
            var c1Mp = cMath.getMidPoint(this.points[0], this.points[1]), // chord 1 midpoint
                c2Mp = cMath.getMidPoint(this.points[1], this.points[2]), // chord 2 midpoint
                c1pm = -(1 / cMath.getSlope(this.points[0], this.points[1])), // chord 1 perpendicular bisector slope
                c2pm = -(1 / cMath.getSlope(this.points[1], this.points[2])); // chord 2 perpendicular bisector slope

            // chord perpendicular bisectors meet at the center
            this.arcCenter.x = (c2Mp.y - (c2pm * c2Mp.x) + (c1pm * c1Mp.x) - c1Mp.y) / (c1pm - c2pm);
            this.arcCenter.y = (c2pm * (this.arcCenter.x - c2Mp.x)) + c2Mp.y;
        },

        _calcArcBounds: function() {
            var validPoints = this.buildValidPointsForArc(),
                minX = fabric.util.array.min(validPoints, 'x'),
                minY = fabric.util.array.min(validPoints, 'y'),
                maxX = fabric.util.array.max(validPoints, 'x'),
                maxY = fabric.util.array.max(validPoints, 'y'),
                width = (maxX - minX) || 1,
                height = (maxY - minY) || 1;

            this.arcBounds = {
                x: minX,
                y: minY,
                width: width,
                height: height
            }
        },

        buildValidPointsForArc: function() {
            var direction = this.getRenderingDirection(),
                possibleBoundingPoints = this.points.concat();

            !this.arcAngles && this._calcArcAngles();

            if (direction) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                    var randomAngle = i * (PI / 2);

                    if (this.arcAngles.startAngle < this.arcAngles.endAngle) {
                        !(this.arcAngles.startAngle <= randomAngle && randomAngle <= this.arcAngles.endAngle) &&
                        possibleBoundingPoints.push(this.generateArcPoint(randomAngle));
                    } else {
                        (this.arcAngles.endAngle <= randomAngle && randomAngle <= this.arcAngles.startAngle) &&
                        possibleBoundingPoints.push(this.generateArcPoint(randomAngle));
                    }
                }

            } else {
                for (var i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
                    var randomAngle = i * (PI / 2);

                    if (this.arcAngles.startAngle < this.arcAngles.endAngle) {
                        (this.arcAngles.startAngle <= randomAngle && randomAngle <= this.arcAngles.endAngle) &&
                        possibleBoundingPoints.push(this.generateArcPoint(randomAngle));
                    } else {
                        !(this.arcAngles.endAngle <= randomAngle && randomAngle <= this.arcAngles.startAngle) &&
                        possibleBoundingPoints.push(this.generateArcPoint(randomAngle));
                    }
                }
            }

            return possibleBoundingPoints;
        },

        generateArcPoint: function(angle) {
            return new fabric.Point(this.arcCenter.x + this.radius * Math.cos(angle), this.arcCenter.y + this.radius * Math.sin(angle));
        },

        _calcArcAngles: function() {

            var angleKeyRepo = ["startAngle", "intermediateAngle", "endAngle"];
            this.arcAngles = this.arcAngles || {};

            this.points.forEach(function(point, index) {
                var a = cMath.getAngle(this.arcCenter, point);

                this.arcAngles[angleKeyRepo[index]] = a < 0 ? ((PI * 2) + a) :
                    a > 2 * PI ? ((PI * 2) - a) : a;
            }, this);
        },

        getRenderingDirection: function() {
            return (((this.points[1].x - this.points[0].x) * (this.points[2].y - this.points[0].y)) -
                ((this.points[1].y - this.points[0].y) * (this.points[2].x - this.points[0].x))) < 0;
        },

        _render: function(ctx, noTransform) {
            if (!this.visible) {
                return;
            }

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(
                noTransform ? this.left : 0,
                noTransform ? this.top : 0,
                this.radius,
                this.arcAngles.startAngle,
                this.arcAngles.endAngle,
                this.getRenderingDirection()
            );
            this._renderFill(ctx);
            this._renderStroke(ctx);
        },

        toObject: function (propertiesToInclude) {
           return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject', propertiesToInclude), {
               points: this.points
           });
       }
    });

fabric.ThreePointArc.fromObject = function(object) {
    return new fabric.ThreePointArc(object.points, object);
};

fabric.ThreePointArc.async = false;

fabric.util.cMath = {
  getSlope : function (startPoint, endPoint) {

        if (!startPoint || !endPoint) {
            console.error('startPoint and endPoint are required to evaluate slope');
            return;
        }

        // hack to get around the indefinte slope problem
        if (endPoint.x == startPoint.x) startPoint.x = startPoint.x + 0.01;
        if (endPoint.y == startPoint.y) endPoint.y = endPoint.y + 0.01;

        return (endPoint.y - startPoint.y) / (endPoint.x - startPoint.x);
    },

    getMidPoint: function (startPoint, endPoint) {

        if (!startPoint || !endPoint) {
            console.error('startPoint and endPoint are required to evaluate slope');
            return;
        }

        return { x: (startPoint.x + endPoint.x) / 2, y: (startPoint.y + endPoint.y) / 2 };
    },

    getAngle: function (startPoint, endPoint, isDegree) {

        if (!startPoint || !endPoint) {
            console.error('startPoint and endPoint are required to evaluate slope');
            return;
        }

        var radians = Math.atan2((endPoint.y - startPoint.y), (endPoint.x - startPoint.x)),
            degrees = fabric.util.radiansToDegrees(radians);

        return isDegree ? degrees < 0 ? 360 + degrees : degrees : radians;
    },

    getLength: function (startPoint, endPoint) {

        if (!startPoint || !endPoint) {
            console.error('startPoint and endPoint are required to evaluate slope');
            return;
        }

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(endPoint.y - startPoint.y, 2) + Math.pow(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, 2));
    }
}

var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var startPoint = new fabric.Point(47.25423728813553, 56.91525423728814),
    intermediatePoint = new fabric.Point( 76.33898305084739,19.8983050847458 ),
    endPoint = new fabric.Point( 105.42372881355931,86 );

 var arc = new fabric.ThreePointArc([startPoint, intermediatePoint, endPoint] , {
        fill:  "#FF0000",
        stroke: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 10
    });
    
canvas.add(arc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.10/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
```

I'm trying to create a three point arc on fabric js (ver: 1.4.10).  What I want is exactly like this:- https://www.screencast.com/t/dMLvcOduEF

I have a points array from which I'm calcualting the startAngle, endAngle, arcCenter, radius, bounding boxc height and widht, top and left. When I draw it, the actual object is not drawing where my mouse points. It adds up the left and top value with the arcCenter.x and arcCenter.y respectively and draws there. Is there any workaround so that my arc can be drawn where my pointer is ?. So that I don't need to write any extra lines of code for moving, rotating and scaling.

What I'm getting is like this:- https://www.screencast.com/t/V9MUgB3pB

added the fiddle!!

Is there any workaround for this ??

Comment: Make a fiddle with your custom object, it will be easy to do some tweak. ;)

Comment: Added the code to fiddle.